# Easy Way To Accomplish Data Compression in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, compression

I am working on an assignment where I have to take a large matrix containing data, and somehow compress the data so that it will be in a form of more manageable size. However, the data needs to be re-utilized as input to something else. (A toolbox, for example). Here's what I've done so far. For this example matrix, I use the find function to give me a matrix of all the indices where the values are non-zero. But I have no idea as to how to use it as input so that the original figure information is retained. I was curious if other folks had any other better (simple) solutions to this.

```
number_1 =     [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...     
                0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
                0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
                0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]; 

number = number_1;
compressed_number = find(number);
compressed_number = compressed_number';
disp(compressed_number)
```

Comment: The way you have defined `number_1` it has only one row. Maybe there are missing semicolons at the end of each row.

Comment: I intend to keep it as a row, it will be reshaped later in the script...

Comment: in that case `find` is your friend. Use `compressed_number = find(number_1)`

Comment: @Mohsen Nosratinia: I edited the code, but my main question was regarding how to recreate the original data.

Comment: With your current algorithm, you get the original back with `newNumber = zeros(size(number_1)); newNumber(compressed_number) = 1;` . But every index found still takes 8 bytes so it's not terribly efficient. See my answer below for a more compact way to store this.

Comment: @ShankarKumar Please don't edit your questions to remove them after they have been answered. The question and its answers may be beneficial for future users of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have only ones and zeros, and the fill factor is not terribly small, your best bet is to store the numbers as binary numbers; if you need the original size, save it separately. I have expanded the code, showing the intermediate steps a little more clearly, and also showing the amount of storage needed for the different arrays. Note - I reshaped your data into a 13x10 array because it displays better.

```
number_1 = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];

n1matrix = reshape(number_1, 10, [])'; % make it nicer to display;
% transpose because data is stored column-major (row index changes fastest).

disp('the original data in 13 rows of 10:');
disp(n1matrix);

% create a matrix with 8 rows and enough columns
n1 = numel(number_1);
nc = ceil(n1/8); % "enough columns"
npad = zeros(8, nc);
npad(1:n1) = number_1; % fill the first n1 elements: the rest is zero

binVec = 2.^(7-(0:7)); % 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 ... powers of two

compressed1 = uint8(binVec * npad); % 128 * bit 1 + 64 * bit 2 + 32 * bit 3...

% showing what we did...
disp('Organizing into groups of 8, and calculated their decimal representation:')
for ii = 1:nc
    fprintf(1,'%d    ', npad(:, ii));
    fprintf(1, '=  %d\n', compressed1(ii));
end

% now the inverse operation: using dec2bin to turn decimals into binary
% this function returns strings, so some further processing is needed
% original code used de2bi (no typo) but that requires a communications toolbox
% like this the code is more portable
decompressed = dec2bin(compressed1);
disp('the string representation of the numbers recovered:');
disp(decompressed); % this looks a lot like the data in groups of 8, but it's a string

% now we turn them back into the original array
% remember it is a string right now, and the values are stored
% in column-major order so we need to transpose
recovered = ('1'==decompressed'); % all '1' characters become logical 1
display(recovered); 

% alternative solution #1: use logical array
compressed2 = (n1matrix==1);
display(compressed2);

recovered = double(compressed2); % looks just the same...

% other suggestions 1: use find
compressed3 = find(n1matrix);  % fewer elements, but each element is 8 bytes
compressed3b = uint8(compressed);  % if you know you have fewer than 256 elements

% or use `sparse`
compressed4 = sparse(n1matrix);

% or use logical sparse:
compressed5 = sparse((n1matrix==1));


whos number_1 comp*


the original data in 13 rows of 10:

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

Organizing into groups of 8, and their decimal representation:
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    =  0
0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    =  15
0    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    =  6
1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    =  193
1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    =  176
0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    =  12
0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    =  3
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    =  0
1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    =  192
0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    =  48
0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    =  12
0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1    =  3
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    =  0
1    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    =  193
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    =  254
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    =  0
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    =  0

the string representation of the numbers recovered:
00000000
00001111
00000110
11000001
10110000
00001100
00000011
00000000
11000000
00110000
00001100
00000011
00000000
11000001
11111110
00000000
00000000

compressed2 =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0


recovered =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Name              Size             Bytes  Class      Attributes

  compressed1       1x17                17  uint8                
  compressed2      13x10               130  logical              
  compressed3      34x1                272  double          
  compressed3b     34x1                 34  uint8     
  compressed4      13x10               632  double     sparse    
  compressed5      13x10               394  logical    sparse    
  number_1          1x130             1040  double
```

As you can see, the original array takes 1040 bytes; the compressed array takes 17. You get almost 64x compression (not quite because 132 is not a multiple of 8); only a very sparse dataset would be better compressed by some other means. The only thing that gets close (and that is super fast) is

```
compressed3b = uint8(find(number_1));
```

At 34 bytes, it is definitely a contender for small arrays (< 256 elements).

Note - when you save data in Matlab (using `save(fileName, 'variableName')`), some compression happens automatically. This leads to an interesting and surprising result. When you take each of the above variables and save them to file using Matlab's `save`, the file sizes in bytes become:

```
number_1     195
compressed1  202
compressed2  213
compressed3  219
compressed3b 222
compressed4  256
compressed5  252
```

On the other hand, if you create a binary file yourself using

```
fid = fopen('myFile.bin', 'wb');
fwrite(fid, compressed1)
fclose(fid)
```

It will by default write `uint8`, so the file sizes are 130, 17, 130, 34, 34 -- sparse arrays cannot be written in this way. It still shows the "complicated" compression having the best compression.

Comment: Thank you, do you mind explaining this a little bit? Also, I think there was a typo in de2bi (dec2bin). I'm kind of confused regarding values you used such as 10,8, and 2^(0:7). Would this work for any matrix?

decompressed =

0000000011
1100000110
0000100000
1100001101
0011000011
0000000000
0000000000
1100001100
0011000011
0000000000
0000100000
1101111111
0000000000

Is there a function to "translate" this back to the original figure?

Comment: Major rewrite and explanation added. Enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, but I have one last question. I don't fully understand the following line: 

recovered = ('1' == decompressed'); % all '1' characters become logical 1

Is this saying, wherever in the string there is a '1' replace it with something???

Comment: Your understanding is perfect. That statement turns the _character_ `'1'` into the _logical_ `1` - everything else will be logical `0`. It is an efficient way to turn a list of characters into numerical values (logic values only take one byte). Of course in my other method they only take one bit - so much more compact. But when you optimize code (speed, size) you can sacrifice readability!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use the `find` function to get all non-zero indices of your array, instead of doing it manually. More info here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Anyways, you will need not only `matrix` but also the original size. So when you pass `matrix` into whatever, you must also pass in `length(number_1)`. This is because `matrix` will not tell you how many 0s there were after the last 1. You can figure it out by subtracting the last value of matrix from the original length (there might be an off-by-one error there).

Comment: I'm not really following you, so you're saying to create a new loop where I add 0 following every non-zero value using the method you've described?

Comment: Nope, you don't need any loops at all. If you use `find` correctly, you can get a matrix whose values are all of the indices in `number_1` which are not zero. But that matrix only tells you where the non-zeros are, and the zeros are "elsewhere". So you need the original length to find out how many zeros were after the last non-zero. Quick example: `find([1,0,1])` will give you `[0,2]`. But `find([1,0,1,0,0])` will also give you `[0,2]`. Without the original length, you will never know if the matrix had none, 2, or 100000 zeros following the last non-zero.

Comment: Of course Matlab arrays start at 1, so `find([1 0 1])` gives `[1 3]`, not `[0 2]`... but you knew that.